# How to find the non one-to-one combinations in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
 bootstrap  cluster_main    cluster_b   distance
    1   0   Cluster 0   Cluster 1   0.002016
    15  0   Cluster 0   Cluster 3   0.001282
    4   0   Cluster 1   Cluster 0   0.000772
    10  0   Cluster 2   Cluster 2   0.000990
    26  1   Cluster 0   Cluster 2   0.001034
    16  1   Cluster 2   Cluster 0   0.000159
    31  1   Cluster 3   Cluster 3   0.000889
    21  1   Cluster 1   Cluster 1   0.000961
    35  2   Cluster 0   Cluster 3   0.099427
    36  2   Cluster 1   Cluster 0   0.067036
    43  2   Cluster 2   Cluster 3   0.102834
    45  2   Cluster 3   Cluster 1   0.069814
```

I would like to find the `bootstrap`s for which there is no one-to-one matching between `cluster_main` and `cluster_b`.

In the above example, the output should be `2` and `0`, because `Cluster 3` in `cluster_b` column for `bootstrap 2`, is "matched" twice and the same happens for `Cluster 0` in the `cluster_main` column for `bootstrap 0`

Comment: Outut is not `2`m because in `10  0   Cluster 2   Cluster 2   0.000990` ? There is match `Cluster 2`

Comment: the output is the `bootstrap` number, not the cluster number.
To put it in other words, for every bootstrap, that there is not a one-to-one match of `cluster_main` to `cluster_b`, i would like the bootstrap number. By one to one, I mean a that no Cluster from `cluster_main` is matched twice to a Cluster from `cluster_b`, and vice versa

Comment: Is possible also say need test if all values `cluster_b` are matched with `cluster_b` per `bootstrap` and it not, get this values? Answer was edited.

Comment: I think the logic can be: for every `bootstrap`, `cluster_main` AND `cluster_b` should have 4 unique values, otherwise show the `bootstrap` number

Comment: Answer was edited for compare sorted values of column or sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#compared sorted values
#f = lambda x: sorted(x['cluster_main']) == sorted(x['cluster_b'])
#comppred sets
#f = lambda x: set(x['cluster_main']) == set(x['cluster_b'])
m = df.groupby('bootstrap').apply(f)
print (m)
bootstrap
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
bootstrap
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

out = m.index[~m]
print (out)
Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64', name='bootstrap')
```

EDIT: I realised first solution was same like comopared sets, so removed.

Here is possible see difference:

```
print (df)
    bootstrap cluster_main  cluster_b  distance
1           0    Cluster 0  Cluster 1  0.002016
15          0    Cluster 0  Cluster 1  0.001282
4           0    Cluster 1  Cluster 0  0.000772
10          0    Cluster 2  Cluster 2  0.000990
26          1    Cluster 2  Cluster 0  0.001034
16          1    Cluster 0  Cluster 2  0.000159
31          1    Cluster 3  Cluster 3  0.000889
21          1    Cluster 1  Cluster 1  0.000961
35          2    Cluster 0  Cluster 0  0.099427
36          2    Cluster 2  Cluster 2  0.067036
43          2    Cluster 2  Cluster 3  0.102834
45          2    Cluster 3  Cluster 2  0.069814


#compared sorted values
f = lambda x: sorted(x['cluster_main']) == sorted(x['cluster_b'])
m = df.groupby('bootstrap').apply(f)
print (m)
bootstrap
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool

f = lambda x: set(x['cluster_main']) == set(x['cluster_b'])
m = df.groupby('bootstrap').apply(f)
print (m)
bootstrap
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I do not think this would work. I edited a bit the input df, but the output should be again [0,2], where as the above code will give [0,1,2]

Comment: I do not understand the difference between the 2 approaches, if I am honest

Comment: @quant - I change data for explain it

Comment: @quant - added sampled ata, can you check it?

Comment: I did check it, in my full dataset as well. It works like a charm, and the logic is clear to me, indeed sorted is the way to go